# Show that $f$ is an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

$A=M(f,B)=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\ 
 -1& 1 & -1\\ 
 1& -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Show that $f$ is an orthogonal projection on a line to be determined. How to solve ?

Comment: I assume that $M(f,B)$ means, “the matrix for $f$ with respect to the basis $B$”.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes correct and B is the canonical basis of R^3 equipped with the canonical euclidean inner product

Comment: Ok, good.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Do you know what eigenvalues and eigenvectors are? Have you studied them before?

Comment: Yes I know, but why can't we prove that transpose of A is A and that A^2=A, so that f is an orthogonal projection

Comment: @PedroAlvarès You also want to find the line that $A$ projects the space onto it. So, just showing that it's an orthogonal projection is not enough. You need more analysis to find the line as in my answer.

Comment: So the line has (1,-1,1) as a director vector ?

Comment: Yes. You can easily check that the eigenvalues of a projection matrix can be $0$ and $1$ only because $A^2=A$. I gave you the geometric intuition but you can prove it algebraically too using the definitions. Obviously, the direction of projection is given by the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $1$ as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

It is geometrically obvious that the direction of the line must be an eigenvector of this transformation because any vector on this line must be projected to itself. Find this eigenvector first (there should be **only one non-zero eigenvalue** based on our geometric intuition). So, find the eigenvector associated with the non-zero eigenvalue of $A$ first. You can normalize the eigenvector if you want. In this particular case, the non-zero eigenvalue is equal to $1$. (I just checked it).

Once you've found it, let's call it $v$, we can decompose our space as follows $$\mathbb{R}^3 = \langle v \rangle \oplus\langle v \rangle ^ {\perp}$$
To show that it's an orthogonal transformation, we should show that it sends $\langle v \rangle ^ {\perp}$ to $0$. Find an orthogonal basis for $\langle v \rangle ^ {\perp}$ and show that $$\ker{A}=\langle v \rangle ^ {\perp}$$

Note that since our matrix $A$ is symmetric, its eigenvectors are orthogonal. So, to find a basis for $\langle v \rangle ^ {\perp}$, you can just find the eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$.

**Edit:** After some calculations as I explained, you can see that $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,-1,1)$ and $\langle v \rangle ^ {\perp}=\langle n,m\rangle$ where $$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,2,1), m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,-1)$$

It is easily seen that $Av=v$ and $An=Am=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\textbf{a} = (1,-1,1)$.  Then for any $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R^3}$, we have
$$
A \mathbf{v} = \frac{\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{v}}{\| \textbf{a}\|^2} \textbf{a},
$$
which one can recognize as the formula for orthogonal projection onto the line spanned by $\textbf{a}$.  (To see that the projection is orthogonal, one can compute the dot product of $\mathbf{v} - A \mathbf{v}$ with $\mathbf{a}$.)